# Initializing second window in separate class (e.g. ChoiceBox)

Tags: java, javafx, initialization, window

I have two window controllers, both of which load an FXML file and show a screen. The first, GUIController is the main window, which spawns a second window, PackageBuilder, inside which the user inputs some data and it's stored.

The second window is spawned via a Button in the main window like so (FXML linked):

```
@FXML private void onNewPackage(ActionEvent e){
    PackageBuilder pb = new PackageBuilder(owner); // Scene owner
}
```

I figured the second class cannot call the JavaFX Application launch method and the original Scene needs to be passed along. So I wrote this inside PackageBuilder:

```
public PackageBuilder(Scene owner) {
    /* Removed redundant setup info */
    fstart(owner);
}
private void fstart(owner) {
    Stage window = new Stage();
    window.initModality(Modality.APPLICATION_MODAL);
    FXMLLoader loader;
    Scene scene;
    try {
        loader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("PackageBuilder.fxml"));
        scene = new Scene(loader.load());
        window.initOwner(owner);
        window.setScene(scene);
        window.showAndWait();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }   
}
```

This all would be all good, if the initialize-method could be called. But it can't. So is there a way to for example initialize the elements of a ChoiceBox anywhere else?

I'm assuming there's a stupid mistake somewhere. There always is.

Comment: Please, watch this video, since you've asked a question 1 hr ago, and nobody answered. Right now, I just have no time enough to help you...
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NgubWgheboI

Comment: Why a new stage instead of a dialog?

Comment: @user1803551 The design is not the issue here. It becomes an issue if in fact this **can't** be done.

Comment: Alright. Post a [MCVE]. I don't see a `ChoiceBox` anywhere, `Application` startup code or the type argument of `private void fstart(owner)`.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The second class with a ChoiceBox to be initialized can implement an interface:

```
public class PackageBuilder implements Initializable{
    @Override
    public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb){
        /* Initialize things needed */
    }
}
```

The method is called before the constructor of the class.

Comment: This is supposed to be an edit of the question, not an answer.

Comment: @user1803551 I answered my own question after coming up with an answer. Why is that supposed to call for an edit? Implementing the Initializable interface is the answer.

Comment: It is not an answer to the question you posted, it might have solved your underlying problem, but what you show in your code is unrelated to this (and there is no `ChoiceBox` anywhere in any case).

Comment: @user1803551 This is getting pointless, but once more, I simply asked about JavaFX' initialization. The ChoiceBox was an example of an item that would require such initialization. I guess my wording was off and I didn't make my self internet-clear.